# VBA excel to loop though file and get specific data

Tags: vba, excel, file, loops

I am working on a macro that needs to go though `xl??` files in a folder and grab specific info from there.

So far this is what I have come up with. But does not seem to be working. Where am I going wrong?

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    'change the address to suite
    MyDir = "\ttsnas02\user_mdocs$\tdf8273\Documents\Rob\External supplier timesheet\CSV Supplier Main\Inbox folder\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")               'change file extension

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Dim isMyCellEmpty As Boolean
        Dim L3T_Supplier_number As String
        Dim L3T_Purchase_Order_number As String
        Dim Supplier_Hours1 As Integer
        Dim Date_for_Supplier_Hours1 As String
        Dim GL_code As String
        Dim mydata As Workbook


        isMyCellEmpty = IsEmpty(Range("L12"))
        If isMyCellEmpty = False Then


            Worksheets("sheet5").Select
            L3T_Supplier_number = Range("J8")
            L3T_Purchase_Order_number = Range("J9")
            GL_code = Range("L12")
            Supplier_Hours1 = Range("I12")

            Set mydata = Workbooks.Open("\\ttsnas02\user_mdocs$\tdf8273\Documents\Rob\External supplier timesheet\posting_supplier.xlsx")
            Worksheets("CSV_Table (3)").Range("a1").Select
            RowCount = Worksheets("CSV_Table (3)").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
            With Worksheets("CSV_Table (3)").Range("a1")
                .Offset(RowCount, 0) = L3T_Supplier_number
                .Offset(RowCount, 1) = L3T_Purchase_Order_number
                .Offset(RowCount, 4) = GL_code
                .Offset(RowCount, 4) = Supplier_Hours1


            End With
            MyFile = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  Please check out the [tour] as well as some great tips in [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Do yourself a favor: (1) Add the 'Option Explicit' line at the top of code; (2) COMPILE your code.  Then you have the file name hard-coded and neve use the file name you find with your 'Dir' statement.

Comment: Also, '... not working...' doesn't help at all. Exactly what piece is *not working*?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Indentation is key**

Now that i've indented your code properly ([using this indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation)). You can clearly see you are missing an `End If` before the `Loop` statement

```
        End With
        MyFile = Dir()
    End If
Loop
```

*note: there may be other issues, but you won't even know about them until you fix this one*

Comment: So I have added this. But when I run the query nothing actually happens. :( Its like the query does not work at all. But it does not error.

Comment: Query? What query? You mean it's not finding your files? Search your code for 'MyFile' and you will see you never use the value that is returned (see my 'hard-coded' comment from earlier)!